# My home page always changes to smartwebsearch.net – is it a Trojan?

Tags: spyware, trojan, homepage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Every time I change the Home page in Firefox or IE it returns back to `http://www.smartwebsearch.net` ?

What is wrong with my PC? Is it a Trojan or spyware?

Comment: See my post here to clean it up...http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533

Comment: Follow the steps in the post linked by Moab (not only his answer, but generally all the advices there). If you don't succeed, report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's the result of a trojan. There is a post [here](http://www.malwareremoval.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=54452) that might be of use. Basically you may be able to remove it with something like [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/malwarebytes_free). Unfortunately if the problem returns or you are unable to run MalwareBytes then there could be an underlying rootkit in which case you'll need something like [rootrepeal](http://sites.google.com/site/rootrepeal/). Did you have any anti-virus software installed before this happened?

Comment: Yes, I have Symantec Endpoint before the problem. I'll try the MalwareBytes.